# Angular script bundles have defer, but are added at end of the body

Tags: html, angular, deferred

Why does angular adds the scripts (script bundles) to the document body instead of the head ?
There doesn't seems to be any gain achieved by such use of defer. Pls see the snapshot for the generated index.html file:-
[image]

Comment: they're added to the body so you can render some kind of placeholder or loading indication while the application loads. putting in head would delay such render till all scripts loaded.

Comment: this is being done because of the historic reasons. maybe someone still uses browsers without "defer" support